# How to find an optimal solution for a missing player in a double-elimination tournament

Tags: soft-question, game-theory, applications

Say that you have a double elimination tournament consisting of four teams with 2 players.  Each of those teams of partners could be: (A,B), (C,D), (E,F), and (G,H), where A is B's partner, C is D's partner, etc.

Now, if one of the players, we'll say it's H for simplicity, can no longer participate in the tournament, what is the best/fairest way to let his partner, G, compete without him?

The goal here is to give G a chance at winning by providing him with another partner (A, B, C, D, E, or F).  However, no player could play on both teams at once.  Ideally, there could be a way to "cancel" the effects of G's partners so that G is neither carrying them nor are they carrying him, but I'm not sure if that is possible.

Comment: You should be more specific in your question. What is the goal, what are the relevant dimensions of the "best way"? Without further information any of the following might be feasible: (a) let G go on alone, (b) let G find a new partner, (c) disqualify G and let the previously losing team advance...

Comment: I tried to clarify above.  (a) is possible, but not preferable.  (c) is not acceptable.  If necessary, (c) would default to (a).  (b) is a solution, but the method by which (b) is accomplished is the whole point of the question.

Comment: Im not sure what is being asked, but here is an idea: Round 1: Game 1 - (A,B) vs (C,D). Game 2 - (E,F) vs (G,X) where X is one of the losers of Game 1.